# Redirect loop error for mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to mod_rewrite:

```
localhost/edit.php?title=?&user_id=?
```

To:

```
localhost/edit/<?php echo $title.'/'.$user_id; ?>
```

So, I can output links as a loop

```
echo '<a href="localhost/edit/'.$title.'/'.$user_id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
```

I'm using:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#Reroute through index.php
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) index.php?title=$1 [NC]

#this is RewriteRule for edit.php UPDATED:
    RewriteRule ^/?edit/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ edit/index.php?title=$1&user_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

However, I get this error:
**This webpage has a redirect loop**

Comment: Is that the only rule there? Do you have any directory structure `edit/A-Za-z0-9_+/0-9+`?

Comment: Yes. RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) index.php?title=$1 [NC].  This is to redirect pages through the index.php.

Comment: Please, post all the contents of the htaccess, it's not easy to debug rewrite rules without knowing all of them, and especially their order.

Comment: I think it's your index rewrite that has the problems since it will match 'edit' and 'index'

Comment: is index.php redirecting the browser to `localhost/edit/<?php echo $title.'/'.$user_id; ?>`?

Comment: I'm not trying to.  Maybe though.  How can I have not conflict?  Since I think index.php takes all requests does edit.php have to be in it a different directory?  Or, can they be in the same directory?

Comment: I've updated the edit.php rule.  It's now index.php in an edit directory.  It works by it's self.  But, as cOle2 said, the index.php is throwing it off.  How can these work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# /edit/title_here/123 -> edit.php?title=title_here&user_id=123
RewriteRule ^edit/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ edit.php?title=$1&user_id=$2 [NC,L]

#Reroute through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+) index.php?title=$1 [NC,L]
```